# Decode string into Readable format PHP

Tags: php, roundcube

Decode The following string to proper human readable string using PHP

```
=?UTF-8?Q?=F0=9F=8E=81Congratulation_Dear,You_are=5FSelected_for=5FOnline?= =?UTF-8?Q?=F0=9F=8E=81cash=5Floan_upto=F0=9F=8E=8110,000/-?=
```

Comment: define "get subject", where are you getting it from, how are you getting it? We can't read minds!

Comment: roundcube has internal functions to acess mail related properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the PHP function [`imap_mime_header_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mime-header-decode.php) to decode it.

For the string posted in the question it returns this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [charset] => UTF-8
            [text] => Congratulation Dear,You are_Selected for_Online
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [charset] => UTF-8
            [text] => cash_loan upto10,000/-
        )

)
```

The unprintable character (`U+1F381`) represents, according to [unicode.org](http://www.unicode.org/charts/beta/nameslist/n_1F300.html), a "wrapped present". It could look like [this](http://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/260/objects/wrapped-gift) if displayed using a font that contains it.